# How to insert prepared text into interactive console in R?

Tags: r, console

I want to paste prepared text into the console to allow the user to skip long text typing and edit that if he/she needs to.

For example, the next line is empty and the console is waiting for user input:

```
authors <- readLines(if (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1") stdin() else "stdin", n = 1)
>[user cursor]
```

And I want to get something like that

```
default <- "Smith, Black, Jackson"
authors <- readLines(if (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1") stdin() else "stdin", n = 1)
> [default][user cursor]
```

Comment: I suggest you switch your whole approach and build a shiny app instead of creating a user interface that reminds me of MS DOS.

Comment: 90% of modern bioinformatics apps look like ms dos, alas. This is due to practical emphasis

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
authors <- readLines(if (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1") stdin() else "stdin", n = 1)
Smith, Black, Jackson
```

Comment: Nope, I need to be able to change authors during a console mode (e.g., remove Smith from authors) not only to add new ones.